# Dual of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ of non-negative integers such that
(i) $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots;$ and
(ii) there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $a_n=0$ for all $n \ge N$.

Define the dual of the sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ belonging to $S$ to be the sequence $(b_1,b_2,\ldots)$, where, for $m\ge 1$, $b_m$ is the number of $a_n$'s which are greater than or equal to $m$

$(i)$ Show that the dual of a sequence in $S$ belongs to $S$
$(ii)$ Show that the dual of the dual of a sequence in $S$ is the original sequence itself.
$(iii)$ Show that the duals of distinct sequences in $S$ are distinct.

I could solve part $(i)$ from the definition of the dual, and from part $(ii)$ I could show that the first term of the dual of dual of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ are equal. But cannot proceed any further. Please help on this.

Comment: Have you tried an example sequence to see what happens when you take the dual?

Comment: The result becomes quite easy to see if we view the sequences in $S$ as partitions, and look at their [Ferrers diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram). The dual of the partition then involves reflecting the corresponding Ferrers diagram along the main diagonal.

Comment: @DanielRust, took the example sequence and I can see the result is obvious but cannot prove it in writing!

Comment: @IvanLoh Sorry, but I did not know about Ferrers diagram. I need to see it before I reach any solution!

Comment: @Hawk It has been almost 2 years since this question was posed. You should chose a solution, and thereby close the question.

Comment: I think Hhsaffar's answer is elegant enough

Comment: @Dan Rust, if I consider the example sequence as $S:(6,4,3,3,2,1,1,0)$ then the dual does not belong to $S$. Now, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I will define matrix $P$ such that $p_{ij}=1 \iff a_i \geq j$ otherwise $p_{ij}=0$.
It is easy to show that sum of row $i$ of $P$ equals $b_i$, and sum of column $j$ of P equals $a_j$.

I define a similar matrix $Q$ such that $Q_{ij}=1 \iff b_i \geq j$ otherwise $Q_{ij}=0$.

Now the only thing that remains is to show $Q=P^T$.

$p_{ij}=1 \to a_i \geq j \to \text{at least i }a_i\geq j \to b_j \geq i \to q_{ji}=1 $
$p_{ij}=0 \to a_i < j \to \text{less than i }a_i\geq j \to b_j < i \to q_{ji}=0 $

So 
$p_{ij}=q_{ji}$

And that is what we wanted.

For part *iii*,show that the corresponding matrices of two different sequences are different in at least one row.

Comment: Good solution (+1)

Answer (score 2):

*Possible Direction Hint:* For 2, let's do an induction on the number of non-zero elements in the original sequence $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, 0, 0, ...)$. For $n=0$ the result is immediate. Now, assume that the result holds for all sequences of length $n \geq 0$. Let's show the same must be true for $n+1$. We consider $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n+1}, 0, 0, ...)$. Now, let $(c_2, c_3, ..., c_{m}, 0, 0, ...)$ be the dual sequence to $(a_2, a_3, ..., a_{n+1}, 0, 0, ...)$, then $m = a_2$. Also note that by the induction hypothesis, the dual to $(c_2, c_3, ..., c_{a_2},0,0,...)$ is $(a_2,a_3, ...,a_{n+1},0,0,...)$. Ok, so now you should be able to convince yourself of the following, if $(b_1, b_2, ..., b_{k}, 0, 0, ...)$ is dual to $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n+1},0,0,...)$ then $k=a_1$ and we have 
$$
(b_1, b_2, ..., b_{a_1}, 0, 0, ...) = (\underbrace{c_2+1, c_3+1, ..., c_{a_2}+1, 1, 1, ..., 1}_{a_1 \text{ non-zero terms}}, 0, 0, ...)
$$
Finally, if you take the dual of $(b_1, b_2, ..., b_{a_1}, ...)$, then using the induction hypothesis and the form of the $b_i$ above, you can recover the original sequence $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{n+1}, 0, 0, ...)$ and conclude the proof.

Comment: That is good but not a very elegant one, I am searching for something better!